# How to use two subsequent ASCII encoded characters in html links?

Tags: html, url, href, mailto

I want my e-mail link to set the e-mail subject to :

```
 Some text & some other text
```

my tag is

```html
<a href="mailto:somemail@example.com?Subject=Some%20text%20%26%20some%20other%20text">mailto</a>
```

and it sets the Subject only to

```
Some text
```

How do I correctly write the %20%26%20 (" & ") part?

Thanks

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Bg8LCo8.png — I can't reproduce the problem. Perhaps it is a bug in your email client or browser.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for the answer but what I did was a stupid mistake that has nothing to do with ASCII encoding, I was just modifying the wrong Localization file...

Answer (score 0):

`mailto:somemail@example.com?subject=some%20text%20%26%20some%20other%20text`

---

I created an open-source tool for making this easy. Enter the strings you want and you'll instantly get the `mailto`:

## [mailto.now.sh](https://mailto.now.sh)

> ⚡️ Template full emails in a mailto

[image: website demo]